# realtime database listener makes CPU skyrocketing

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i'm implementing chatting feature with realtime database of Firebase and React,
and i wrote like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    messagesListeners(pid)
  }, [])

  const messagesListeners = async (pid: string) => {
    const messages = [];

    realtimeService
      .ref(`messages/post-${pid}`)
      .on('child_added', DataSnapshot => {
        messages.push(DataSnapshot.val())
        setComments([...messages])
      })
  }
```

but it's making browser's CPU skyrocketing. i think it's because of the part of "setComments". when i removed that part (setComments), this issue doesn't happen. if there are 100 of comments, that set comments 100 times.

How can i bring new comments without CPU's skyrocketing?

Comment: Probably it is sky-rocketing due to something else in your code, can you please show us the rest of it? This component and probably childs of this component, setting data and rendering is not heavy itself. Also, im not seeing the `.off()` call to stop the listener on component destroy, for example.

Comment: @SergeySosunov i'd tested after commenting out other codes, even i tried rendered nothing apart from that part. still i can't find out which part is wrong :'(

Comment: Show us please the completed components, maybe minified ones, we need to reproduce your code behavior somehow, something is constantly rerendering, or some useEffects are executed more than needed, the code you show is not resource-consuming, plus you have an issue even with Frank's code, which runs only once. If you can prepare a codesandbox environment for us, for example - we will be able to investigate. Just dont inlude your personal firebase config data, it is considered as "public" but still not good until security is configured.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in here::

```
setComments([...messages])
```

This call, adds your entire `messages` array to the end of the existing `comments` array. This leads to an exponentially growing `comments` array:

| child_added | messages | comments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| one | [one] | [one] |
| two | [one,two] | [one,one,two] |
| three | [one,two,three] | [one,one,two,one,two,three] |
| four | [one,two,three,four] | [one,one,two,one,two,three,one,two,three,four] |
| five | [one,two,three,four,five] | [one,one,two,one,two,three,one,two,three,four,one,two,three,four,five] |
| ... |  |  |

So the minimal fix is to set the `comments` array to the `messages`, instead of constantly appending:

```
setComments(messages)
```

---

You can also reduce the number of calls to `setComments` by listening to a `value` event, instead of `child_added`. The `value` event will fire only once for all comments, which you can then process with:

```
const messagesListeners = async (pid: string) => {
  realtimeService
    .ref(`messages/post-${pid}`)
    .on('value', snapshot => {
      const messages = [];
      snapshot.forEach((child) => {
        messages.push(child.val())
      });
      setComments(messages)
    })
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but why do you think it grows exponentially? setComments([...messages]) is just replacing `comments` with new array, constructed from "messages", not appending. Also, i think for Chat it is important to have the live messages to appear instead of getting them once on "value"

Comment: i've changed like above, but my computer is still burning because of the part of " setComments(messages) ", still when i remove that part, everything is fine.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, was confused by "will fire only once for all comments", but as per docs it was "once with the initial data and again every time the data changes", anyway, question about exponential grow still actual

Comment: @YOY: can you add an update to the bottom of your question to show how you now implemented it?